# Timeline indicators using CSS and HTML

Tags: html, css, css-shapes

[image: Timeline with left and right arrows]

I am trying to recreate this image using a combination of CSS and HTML with no luck. Please advise.

Current Code:

```css
.lens-profile-timeline {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 60px 0 80px;
  border-bottom: 8px solid #39752c;
  position: relative;
}
.lens-profile-timeline li {
  position: absolute;
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  border: 13px solid #39752c;
  border-radius: 16px;
  background: #fff;
  margin-top: -10px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
}
.lens-profile-timeline time,
.lens-profile-timeline p {
  left: -27px;
  top: -40px;
  position: absolute;
  width: 70px;
  text-align: center;
}
.lens-profile-timeline time {
  margin-top: 70px;
  font-size: 18px;
}
.lens-profile-timeline p {
  margin-top: -0px;
  font-size: 10px;
  line-height: 1.1;
}
.lens-profile-timeline p:after {
  content: "";
  height: 8px;
  border-left: 1px solid #39752c;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  left: 35px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-3">
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <ol class="lens-profile-timeline point">
      <li style="left: 0;">

        <time>1970</time>

      </li>
      <li style="left: 45%;">
        <time datetime="2003-01-01">2003</time>

      </li>

      <li style="right: 0;">
        <time>2013</time>
        <p class="hidden">Current Year</p>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-3">
  </div>
</div>
```

Above represents the current code being used to generate the image. However you will notice there are several elements which are missing.

Comment: FYI the original is probably an image... so why try to do it in HTML and CSS when its like 1000% harder if not impossible to achieve the same thing.

Comment: @Seabizkit - the element needs to be created dynamical by any content author.

Comment: @Thaillie - The code has been posted

Comment: You should add more info. Do you need it to be responsive? Are there any clickable elements?

Comment: @pabloFdz - no the elements do not need to be clickable and no it does not need to be responsive.

Comment: @RobertFarr I stand corrected!!!.....Nice.. I'm impressed at Manoj Kumar

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do it with a combination of pseudo elements, CSS triangles and linear-gradients.

1. The `linear-gradient(to right, #AFCB6D, #126A38);` will create a mixed background color effect.
2. The triangles at the end can be created using [CSS triangles concept](https://davidwalsh.name/css-triangles) using pseudo-elements.
3. The indicators are created with pseudo element circles as well. The indicator text can be specified within `content: " "` or remove the pseudo-elements and specify the text within `div` for better customization.

**Regular text without using CSS content:**

```css
.timeline {
  width: 500px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #AFCB6D, #126A38);
  position: relative;
  font-family: Roboto;
}
.timeline::before,
.timeline::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  top: -5px;
}
.timeline::before {
  left: -20px;
  border: 10px solid #AFCB6D;
  border-color: transparent #AFCB6D transparent transparent;
}
.timeline::after {
  right: -20px;
  border: 10px solid #126A38;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #126A38;
}
.indicators {
  position: relative;
}
.indicator-1,
.indicator-2,
.indicator-3 {
  border: 5px solid #AFCB6D;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  top: -5px;
  position: absolute;
}
.indicator-1 {
  left: 10px;
}
.indicator-2 {
  border-color: #5B9951;
  left: 240px;
}
.indicator-3 {
  border-color: #126A38;
  left: 475px;
}
.indicator-text {
  position: relative;
  top: 15px;
}
.indicator-1 .indicator-text {
  left: -20px;
}
.indicator-2 .indicator-text {
  left: -15px;
}
.indicator-3 .indicator-text {
  left: -10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
  <div class="indicators">
    <div class="indicator-1">
      <div class="indicator-text">Standard</div>
    </div>
    <div class="indicator-2">
      <div class="indicator-text">Better</div>
    </div>
    <div class="indicator-3">
      <div class="indicator-text">Best</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Titles using content property:**

```css
.timeline {
  width: 500px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 20px;
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #AFCB6D, #126A38);
  position: relative;
  font-family: Roboto;
}
.timeline::before,
.timeline::after {
  content: " ";
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  width: 0px;
  top: -5px;
}
.timeline::before {
  left: -20px;
  border: 10px solid #AFCB6D;
  border-color: transparent #AFCB6D transparent transparent;
}
.timeline::after {
  right: -20px;
  border: 10px solid #126A38;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #126A38;
}
.indicator {
  border: 5px solid #5B9951;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  top: -5px;
  position: relative;
}
.indicator::after {
  content: "\a Best";
  white-space: pre;
  border: 5px solid #126A38;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  top: -5px;
  left: 230px;
  position: absolute;
}
.indicator::before {
  content: "\a Standard";
  white-space: pre;
  border: 5px solid #AFCB6D;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  top: -5px;
  left: -240px;
  position: absolute;
}
.spacer {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline">
  <div class="indicator">
    <div class="spacer"></div>Better
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is almost perfect but I have no way of adding the titles to the check points.

Comment: I have added the text within `content`.

Comment: Is there any way to have all 3 front facing? Similar to how you have "Best"

Comment: I am not sure what you meant by front-facing like "Best". I have edited the code without using CSS content property. Is that what you are looking for? :)

Comment: Yes... This is perfect.

Answer (score 3):

It's not perfect, but using CSS 3 gradients, and changing a few numbers, you can get something pretty close to your picture (minus the arrows)

I wrapped it all up in a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/jonulinile/edit?html,css,output).

Hope this helps,
Sean

Comment: Thanks but the arrows is what I really need